# Posting data with aiohttp to flask server fails

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a process which generates some data then uploads it to a web server. Both operations take some time, so I would like to speed the process up by sending the data asynchronously. I also do not want to overload the server, so I want to restrict uploading to one file at a time. I can't get this working and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I have set up testing using a simple Flask server. I have created a test example using `requests` which works fine. However, when I try to upload data with `asyncio` it throws an exception some of the time. It seems to be related to how quickly I make the calls, sometimes it's fine, sometimes it throws but once it starts failing it seems to cascade. I am trying to ensure I'm only making one call at a time which should mimic requests.

Given it seems to work fine with requests, I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong on asyncio side.  I have tried a range of different implementations with no luck.

This is the code for the Flask server:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    return jsonify({'status': 'OK'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

This is the code for the requests and asyncio upload implementations:

```py
import asyncio, requests
from aiohttp import ClientSession

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'

def get_data():
    return {'a': 'b'}

async def send_data(session, data):
    async with session.post(url, json=data) as response:
        response_data = await response.json()
        print(response_data)

async def upload_asyncio(loop):
    """attempt at asyncio upload"""
    task = None
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for _ in range(20):
            # dummy get data function for testing
            data = get_data()
            # I want to wait until the previous upload has complete before uploading next chunk
            if not task is None:
                await task
            task = asyncio.create_task(send_data(session, data))
        if not task is None:
            await task

def upload_requests():
    """working equivalent using requests"""
    for _ in range(20):
        data = get_data()
        with requests.post(url, json=data) as resp:
            response_data = resp.json()
            print(response_data)

#upload_requests()

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(upload_asyncio(loop))
```

the exception which gets raised is:

```
Exception in callback _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)
handle: <Handle _ProactorBasePipeTransport._call_connection_lost(None)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\John\anaconda3\envs\py310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 162, in _call_connection_lost
    self._sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```